# JavaScript conflict preventing page from displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experiencing a conflict in my page with jquery scripts, the features(top menu or image slider) in the page does not open unless the page is reloaded several times.
http://www.in2info.com/leroyalcorporatev2/beirut/restaurants.php?v=4

Can someone help me fix it.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just as a heads up. Ideally you should provide some sample code... as a help me fix my problem question isn't normally as well received as this one

Comment: true normally this gets 5 downvotes and 3 close votes in no time

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function)     
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function)
```

**Cause:**

Which could mean that wherever you're loading `$` from *(I'm assuming jQuery)*, might **NOT** be loading in time, thus when the site gets hit initially, jQuery isn't ready, and the menu will be broken.

Make sure you're adding jQuery in [correctly](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

**Example:**

```
<head>
     <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your browser console debug window. I used chrome (press F12)
[image]
Jquery is not loaded and hence the issue.
Put your jquery reference under header as below:-

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use

```
    <head>
.....
        <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
            $.getScript("js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js");
        });</script>
....
    </head>
```

in your head tag to load jquery

$ is jquery

just put jquery straight into the head

e.g.

```
<head>
...
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
... //use $ now
</head>
```

after the script line jquery becomes available ( $ ).

Comment: Tried It locally, still having problem. jQuery(....).camera is not a function. The menu and the slider freezes

Comment: @GeorgeH I can see that you are using requireJS. Maybe stop using it until you figure things out? On the website you showed me you are loading jquery twice. This is bad. Remove require JS for the moment or learn how to use it. I advice against using it since it takes you quite a while to get it working.

To your error, you don't load camera.min.js in time. Just put it right after `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: generally, when it says "it is not a function" means it hasn't been loaded at the correct time, is therefore null or undefined